# Finding variables in a 2x2 matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, cryptography

How do I find $b$ and $d$ in the equation: $\begin{bmatrix}6 & 25\\12 & 15\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}2 & b\\5 & d\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}22 & 17\\10 & 22\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Something is wrong. The upperleft entry of the right hand side isn't equal to what you get for that entry on the left hand side

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I show you the whole question I was asked on my maths assignment and get your input on how to do it? I must be doing something wrong. I can see that you are correct, but I do not see what else that number could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the first column of the resultant matrix is $[137,99]^T$.

On the one hand

$$\begin{bmatrix}6 & 25\\12 & 15\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2 & b\\5 & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}137 & 17\\99 & 22\end{bmatrix}$$

and on the other hand

$$\begin{bmatrix}6 & 25\\12 & 15\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2 & b\\5 & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}137 & 6b+25d\\99 & 12b+25d\end{bmatrix}.$$

We, then, have to solve the following system of linear equations:

$$6b+25d=17$$
$$12b+25d=22.$$

This should not cause any problem:

The solutions are $b=\frac56$ and $d=\frac{12}{25}$. These numbers give the second column of the given resultant matrix.

Comment: This was exactly my thinking, but when I solve those linear equations and then substitute them back in I don't get the correct answer I should also mention that b and d should not be decimals because this is supposed to encrypt FLY OUT into VJQ VXK where A=1, B=2 etc... I may just be doing something wrong but I have tried multiple times.

Comment: OK. Let's try to solve our system of  equations.